# Github like data schema?

Tags: mysql, database, redis

I'm learning and trying to make a site but I'm a bit confused about a data model.  My site is similar to github in that you can follow people and copy/share stuff(similar to forking/pull requests).  How can I make a data model to store this?

Basically, I write an article and the article is associated to me. Then you come and 'fork' my article, do I make a copy of it? or is it just a link? then after editing your version you send me a request to merge our content together(I don't want to overwrite the data but not sure how to do it in a way that is captures the differences).  To make matters worst for me, I want to have versioning on edits, which makes it complicated when I'm doing versioning on forked data.

I don't know where to start..I don't need the answer but any suggestions on how to model this fork/merge interaction would be great.  I haven't decided if I'll use redis or mysql yet but a general answer is okay if I can apply the logic to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 models: Article and ArticleRevision. User has many articles associated with him (owner of the article), and article has many revisions:

- Article (id, user_id, current_revision_id, created_at) has many ArticleRevisions
- ArticleRevision (id, article_id, title, body, created_at, parent_revision_id) belongs to Article, belongs to ArticleRevision, has many ArticleRevisions

Current revision of Article is determined by `current_revision_id` field. Revision has a parent revision - this is a revision from which it is originated.

When someone forks an article:

- Clone the article
- Clone the latest revision of the article and optionally reset the parent of newly created revision (so history will be empty).
- Set the owner and current revision of the newly created article

Comment: Thanks!  Few questions, what do you mean 'clone the article' do you mean copy the contents from the article model but change the user_id?  Also what happens when someone tries to merge it with the original? Does it do the same but in reverse(copy the article back but give change the user_id)?  I'm not a huge github user but I thought they do something to show the differences between the changes(like a diff between the two), not sure if they are doing it on demand or if its part of the database model.

Comment: @Error_404 Yes, by clone I mean to copy the original article and change some fields (owner_id, current_revision_id). Merging involves 2 different revisions, as long as revision id's are different it doesn't matter if revision is going to be merged with the original.